# Upload to firebase storage returns TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to my firebase storage with this code

```
 async function uploadData() {
  console.log('good job')
  const randomName = Math.random().toString(36)
  const uri = image;

  setUploading(true)
   console.log(image)
  
  const childPath = firebase.storage().ref().child('drivers').child('truck').child(randomName)
  const response = await fetch(image)
  const blob = await response.blob()
  const task = childPath.put(blob, { contentType: 'image/jpeg'})

  const taskProgress = snapshot => {
    //setUploading = true
    console.log('transferred: ', snapshot )
  }
  const taskCompleted = () => {
   task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {

    saveToFireStore(snapshot)
      console.log(snapshot)
    })
  }
  const taskError = snapshot => {
   // setUploading(false)
    Alert.alert(
      "",
      snapshot,
      [
        
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => setUploading(false) }
      ])
    console.log(snapshot)
  }
  task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted)
}
```

but it returns this error `TypeError: Network request failed` at first I thought my internet connection was bad and hence the cause but I have tested my internet and it seems okay enough to upload a data online Which is why I feel its a code issue. maybe firebase made some changes I don't know about or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you think about internet connection or any the `error` makes sense it's clearly defines that you are sending the wrong type of input data.

> core cause is you are defining `contentType: 'image/jpeg'` but actually sending as a blob both have different MIME type

So remove the `contentType` and you have to set the extension like `.jpg` to the image name

```
async function uploadData() {

//const randomName = Math.random().toString(36);  name must have extension like .jpg
const randomName = "image.jpg"; // any other type as your wish

setUploading(true);

const childPath = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref()
    .child("drivers/truck")
    .child("truck")
    .child(randomName);
const response = await fetch(uri);
const blob = await response.blob();
const task = childPath.put(blob); // don't have to specify type

...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error TypeError: Network request failed is a general JavaScript error that occurs when a network request fails to complete. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue when uploading an image to Firebase Storage:

1. Verify URI:
   Ensure the uri variable contains a valid URL to your image.
   Log the uri to the console before the fetch to ensure it's what you expect.

```html
console.log(uri);
```

2. Network Permissions:

If you are testing on a mobile device, ensure you have network permissions set in your app manifest.

3. Firebase Storage Rules:

Verify your Firebase Storage rules to ensure they allow the operation you're attempting.

```html
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to revert to secure rules once you've identified the issue.

4. CORS Configuration:

If running from a web browser, ensure your Firebase Storage CORS configuration allows requests from your domain.

5. Internet Connection:

Check if your internet connection is stable and try again.

6. Firebase SDK Version:

Ensure you're using a recent version of the Firebase SDK.

```html
npm install firebase@latest
```

7. Enhanced Error Handling:

Update your error handling to log more information about the error.

```js
const taskError = snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot.message);
  Alert.alert("", snapshot.message, [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => setUploading(false) }]);
}
```

8. Console Errors:

Check the console for any other errors or warnings that might provide more information.

9. Test in Different Environment:

Test the upload on a different device or network to see if the problem persists.